# Convergence of convolution with a function which has Cesaro average

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, lebesgue-integral

Assume that a function $g$ has Cesaro averages
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x g(y) dy = \lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{x}\int_{-x}^0 g(y) dy =: \bar g \tag{1}
$$
and $f$ is integrable.

Under which additional assumptions does it hold that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) g(ax) dx \to \bar g \cdot \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx, a\to+\infty?
$$
I do not want to assume too much regularity for $f$ and/or $g$. (In my case $g$ is a sample of a special stationary ergodic process.)

Comment: Hi. I'm not in the most creative mood right now. Can you ask a concrete question? If not, I understand.

Comment: @mathworker21, yes, I could ask a very concrete question (which, in fact, I have answered already), but for some reasons I had chosen to ask a more general version.